# What is the cost of a Spark shuffle?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

Data information:

- your data have *N* lines;
- each line is *b* bytes long;
- each line belongs to one among *G* groups, given by numeric variable `theGroup`;
- initially, groups are randomly sorted accross partitions.

Cluster information:

- your `SparkContext` has *E* executors;
- each executor has *n* nodes;
- transferring 1 KB from one executor to another costs *pingTime* (aggregation time included)
- there's only one output cable and one input cable on each executor.

Your mission: `groupBy(theGroup)` using Spark, ***iff*** it's not too long to do.

Big Problem: **What's a good estimate of how much time *T* this operation is going to take?**

---

Wild guesses so far: I would imagine *T* to be:

- increasing in *N* (*n.E*)⁻¹ log( *N* (*n.E*)⁻¹ )

  - idea: because there are *N* (*n.E*)⁻¹ lines on each node and they might have to get sorted first
- increasing in *b*, obviously
- increasing in *pingTime*
- increasing in *G*, but I have no idea how: perhaps increasing in *G*² while *G* < *N*
- decreasing in *n*

I need an estimate of the magnitude order of *T*, but I'm still missing terms (like the relationship between *E* and *G*).

Comment: Assume the worst case scenario where all data is on node _i_ but has to be transfered to node _j_ (for all _g_ in _G_ _hash(g) = j_) Then all you have to consider is the cost of preparing shuffle (sorting and stuff) and transfer.

Comment: Yep, in that case it would be something like T ~ b N log( N ) pingTime/1000.

Comment: Actually, the question would be even more interesting if you consider some complexity parameter (entropy-like thing) for the initial distribution of groups through nodes. If your data are already sorted by `theGroup`, the shuffle will most certainly be faster.